# Modelling operational risk for Basel pillar 2 (internal model for OpRisk VaR)

Tags: value-at-risk, banking-regulations, basel, oprisk

I am somewhat familiar with OpRisk for pillar 1. As far as I know OpRisk for pillar 1 will be replaced by standard approaches soon.
So what is left is proper modelling in pillar 2.

What are best practice and/or regulatory references on how an internal model for OpRisk (with the result of a value-at-risk or similar) for pillar 2 should look like?

From a [talk on the web](https://www.uts.edu.au/research-and-teaching/our-research/quantitative-finance-research/events/operational-risk-models) I found the usual topics from a loss distribution approach (LDA):

- Loss Distribution Approach (LDA): frequency/severity, models, heterogeneity
- Modelling large losses: EVT, heavy tailed distributions, single loss approximation
- Estimation: maximum likelihood approach, method of moments; Bayesian, MCMC, EM.
- Combining data and scenario analysis: Bayesian approach, p-boxes, credibility
- Numerical methods for Aggregation of risks: MC, FFT, Panjer recursion
- Capital allocation: Euler allocation, marginal allocations

Would the regulatory expect all of this for pillar 2?

Comment: It's hard to give you an answer to the question when you're asking several. Perhaps posting them separately will give you better feedback?

Comment: @not2qubit I give some more details what the expectation could be. But the question marks all point to the following: So what is left is proper modelling in pillar 2.What are best practice and/or regulatory references on how an internal model for OpRisk (with the result of a value-at-risk or similar) for pillar 2 should look like?

Comment: @not2qubit If the standard approach is used in pillar 1, what will happen to pillar 2? Will every bank just reuse their LDA model from pillar 1 for 2. What if the LDA model is too much effort to mantain, what can in such cases be done for pillar 2?

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer put perhaps partial help.

1. *What alternatives do we have for pillar 2?*

Hard to say. There doesn't seem to be any specific alternatives, apart adjusting your old procedures to whatever the institutions you are working with require.

2: *Does it have to be a loss distribution approach (LDA) or could it be something between LDA and a standard approach (SA)? Something less challenging as an LDA but more sensitive than an SA?*

From the first § of [Basel 4: the way ahead](https://assets.kpmg.com/content/dam/kpmg/xx/pdf/2018/02/basel-4-the-way-ahead.pdf):

> The BCBS has introduced a single non‑model based method for the
>   calculation of operational risk (OpRisk) capital, the Standardised
>   Approach (SA). This will replace all three existing approaches for
>   OpRisk under Pillar 1: the Basic Indicator Approach (BIA), the
>   (Alternative) Standardised Approach (TSA/ASA) and the Advanced
>   Measurement Approach (AMA). The SA will apply from 1 January 2022.

So, yes, it seem that it will be an updated SA.

Also from [here](https://www.risk.net/comment/5386401/basel-op-risk-modelling-blow-shifts-focus-to-pillar-2):

> The simplicity of current approaches to loss event dependency warrants
>   considerable improvement, and with machine learning techniques coming
>   to the forefront of model construction, investing in enrichment of
>   internal data – from systems to management surveys, employee
>   satisfaction surveys and cultural assessments – may, in time, provide
>   insights into loss drivers and the dependency of losses across an
>   organisation. This area, however, **is under development and some way
>   off** inclusion in Pillar 2 capital calculation methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wonder if more references can be found. What I read so far is: use LDA for pillar 2 as there is no alternative. Is this true?